# Loading a website through another website

Tags: html, iframe, cross-site

I am trying to understand how it is possible to load a website using an iframe, but make all links go through your site.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not, What you're willing to do is called a proxy.

You should get the target site in your server-side script (PHP+CURL e.g), find and replace links programatically and represnet the new data to the user.

Comment: in fact your server side script should act as a Client + Server at the same time, getting the target site as a client (e.g CURL) and presenting the changed site as a server

Comment: There are open source software, like PHProxy or Glype.

Answer (score 1):

You can't accomplish this with just HTML. The site you are linking to has a server-side application that transparently rewrites all the links in the page to go through their website.

Comment: Ah-ha! Brilliant, thanks. I was thinking something along these lines. That really shouldn't be a problem. Can't it be done with regex and .htaccess or similar technology? Can you point me towards more info, please?

Comment: @santa, It looks like there is a module for Apache called `mod_proxy_html` that does something like this. Another way to do it is to have a server-side application/script that fetches the target page, parses the HTML (using an HTML parsing library, for instance), finds all the `<a>` elements and rewrites their `href` attribute, serializes the page and sends it to the client.